# Is the 'DocuSign for Salesforce' AppExchange app configurable via an API?

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I'm trying to automate the configuration of the **DocuSign for Salesforce** AppExchange app in our **SFDC** sandbox.

Specifically I'd like to specify the account used to connect **DocuSign** to **Salesforce** (the values available under the **DocuSign Admin** > **Account** tab within the **DfS** app).

To be clear, the app is already installed, I just want to modify its configuration.

**Question:**

Is there any way to automate that?  Of course I could use UI automation, but that's a last resort.

Most **SFDC** objects are accessible via an **API** and **DocuSign** itself is accessible via an **API**. But it's not clear whether the **DfS** app itself is.

Answer (score 1):

The account used to connect DocuSign to Salesforce is setup when you login via a docusign account after installing the app. Can you explain a bit more regarding the automation you are trying to invoke here ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  In our test environment, we have multiple (~70) SFDC sandboxes, all cloned from a common master, which already has the DfS app installed.  Each SFDC sandbox needs its own corresponding DocuSign sandbox.  I'm trying to automate the provisioning and configuration of those DocuSign sandboxes without clicking through the UI 70 times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DocuSign for Salesforce Essentials](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FK9gtUAD) package to utilize the [Apex toolkit](https://developers.docusign.com/salesforce/guides/apex-toolkit), which can help you automate some processes. This is not the same package as the classic DocuSign eSignature for Salesforce package. It has limited features outside of the Apex toolkit. You can have both installed at the same time, as long as you have version 7.4.2 or newer. Not sure what specifically you're looking to automate, but this would probably be a good place to start.